# How to color arcs with arc.js?

Tags: leaflet, arc-js

I've been using [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js/) and I was trying to see if there was any way to color the arcs, except for the normal blue shown([ex](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/arcjs/)). I tried looking around with the arc options, but I couldn't really find anything too useful. Is there anyway I can do this with arc.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.geojson` accepts all the [Path](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) options as well, so you can set the `color` parameter in the `L.geojson` options to a color of your choice.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([42.87596410238254, -100.546875], 4);

// Start and end points, in x = longitude, y = latitude values
var start = { x: -122, y: 48 };
var end = { x: -77, y: 39 };
var generator = new arc.GreatCircle(start, end, { name: 'Seattle to DC' });
var line = generator.Arc(100, { offset: 10 });
L.geoJson(line.json(), {
color: "#ff0000"
}).addTo(map);
```